# Add a header to each column

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I would like to add to my script a header for each of my columns, here is my code:

```
 $products = $order->getProducts();

    // Création CSV détail de commande
    $filename = $order->reference . '_details.csv';
    if (!$fp = fopen($this->exportDir . '/' . $filename, "w")) {
        throw new Exception('Impossible de créer fichier export : ' . $this->exportDir . '/' . $filename);
    }

    $header = ['CMD', 'Reference', 'Quantity', 'Unit Price', 'Total Price'];

    fputcsv($fp, $header);

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $data = array();
        $data[] = $order->reference;
        $data[] = (string)$product['product_reference'];
        $data[] = $product['product_quantity'];
        $data[] = number_format($product['unit_price_tax_incl'], 2);
        $data[] = number_format($product['total_price_tax_incl'], 2);

        fputcsv($fp, $data, $this->csvDelimiter, $this->csvEnclosure);
    }

    fclose($fp);
```

[image: header]

I try different thing but the header puts that on a cell .. thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by a header for each column?

Comment: Example: 1st column = CMD
2nd column = Reference .... my csv file

Comment: What's a "column" in this context?

Comment: Excel file columns (CSV)

Comment: A CSV file is merely a text file with some rules. The concept of a "header" is nothing more than naming your row #1's cells. You're code appears correct so can you explain what you expect versus what you are getting? Screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: Also note that a CSV file is vastly different than an `xls/x` file. Just because Excel can open CSVs does not mean that all of the features are available in a CSV.

Comment: I have attached the result I have. The problem is that the whole header puts on one ceculle

Comment: @Sinto why would that fix it?

Comment: Why are you not putting the header the same way as the data ? (e.i. same delimitter, enclosure etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the header delimiter and stuff so that it matches your data:

Change:

```
$header = ['CMD', 'Reference', 'Quantity', 'Unit Price', 'Total Price'];

fputcsv($fp, $header);
```

into

```
$header = ['CMD', 'Reference', 'Quantity', 'Unit Price', 'Total Price'];

fputcsv($fp, $header, $this->csvDelimiter, $this->csvEnclosure);
```